# Any workaround for weird behaviour with position: sticky & box-shadow on chrome 56?

Tags: html, css, angular

The issue is when using box-shadow in conjunction with position: sticky it offsets the content to the right bottom a little bit instead of staying at the the top as it should. The behavior is present only in Chrome 56 to my knowledge and doesn't affect beta & dev version of Chrome, Firefox (stable or otherwise) and Safari.

To replicate this create a sample HTML page that has some content to scroll through and a navigation bar

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br>
<main>
  <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet kevin sirloin bresaola, meatloaf chuck short loin andouille picanha pork. Meatloaf sausage ribeye, fatback biltong jerky sirloin kielbasa kevin jowl cupim pork chop tail. Cow chuck bacon, fatback filet mignon drumstick
    t-bone turkey. Landjaeger sausage beef ribs, andouille fatback swine ground round burgdoggen turkey meatloaf shoulder meatball short ribs. Pork chop pork belly meatloaf leberkas capicola fatback landjaeger. Tail capicola pork chop rump meatball flank
    kielbasa swine kevin ground round pork tenderloin cupim sirloin shank. Ham hock kielbasa biltong, rump leberkas pastrami landjaeger brisket. Bresaola chicken ball tip jowl beef meatball turducken ham tail porchetta tongue capicola jerky short ribs.
    Flank brisket tongue pork loin frankfurter prosciutto sirloin shank burgdoggen salami hamburger doner corned beef drumstick. Beef ribs chicken tri-tip drumstick, andouille short loin sirloin porchetta. Cupim bacon filet mignon chicken ball tip, shoulder
    beef ribs shank leberkas short ribs pork turkey biltong kielbasa ground round. Fatback turducken jowl beef ribs hamburger swine chicken sausage pork belly corned beef pig pork. Ham hock pork loin hamburger corned beef venison, ham chuck leberkas short
    ribs. Short ribs filet mignon leberkas bacon turducken beef ribs pork belly ribeye sirloin t-bone prosciutto. Ham picanha sausage, pastrami rump t-bone turkey tenderloin kielbasa short loin. Short loin tongue bacon drumstick filet mignon corned beef.
    Sirloin flank landjaeger cow swine kevin capicola. Kielbasa cupim doner, boudin venison turducken ham landjaeger pork loin shoulder pork chop shank filet mignon sausage hamburger. Burgdoggen corned beef alcatra turducken venison tongue porchetta andouille.
    Fatback leberkas filet mignon burgdoggen venison ribeye chuck. Tenderloin turducken pork belly tail chicken biltong, ribeye jowl corned beef. Swine brisket t-bone tongue, bresaola pig kevin. Strip steak salami rump flank pork chop alcatra. Beef ribs
    burgdoggen ribeye kevin t-bone picanha, landjaeger filet mignon shank frankfurter alcatra ham prosciutto fatback. Venison shank pastrami hamburger ham hock. Frankfurter chuck jerky, pancetta flank sausage turkey tenderloin. Frankfurter ham hock filet
    mignon leberkas, chuck pork chop brisket chicken corned beef tri-tip. Bacon shank ball tip, prosciutto beef alcatra capicola landjaeger t-bone brisket sirloin ground round shoulder pig. Ham hock pork frankfurter alcatra burgdoggen picanha pig. Capicola
    drumstick cupim, chuck beef ribs pork loin biltong. Short ribs chuck jerky turkey ham fatback. Flank meatball sausage shank filet mignon doner strip steak hamburger landjaeger meatloaf ribeye salami boudin rump pastrami. Fatback filet mignon turkey,
    hamburger tri-tip turducken pastrami salami pork chop pork loin tenderloin. Tri-tip alcatra short ribs pancetta beef ribs turkey ball tip sausage pork loin corned beef. Tongue beef pastrami, t-bone turducken meatloaf pork belly. Beef pork meatloaf
    jerky doner andouille, ham hock swine capicola boudin turducken short ribs pork loin ball tip. Pig sausage ham tri-tip porchetta ball tip rump tongue burgdoggen swine. Pork loin capicola spare ribs tri-tip brisket jerky. Drumstick short ribs beef
    rump, tail filet mignon venison fatback turducken porchetta pig tri-tip pork chop biltong kevin. Tongue chicken ribeye t-bone. Landjaeger boudin sausage turducken salami brisket, meatloaf alcatra ham hock ball tip porchetta tongue spare ribs tail
    tri-tip. Beef ribs leberkas doner pork loin turkey ham hock burgdoggen andouille cupim. Capicola boudin bacon strip steak cow beef ribs brisket ground round doner sausage. Swine capicola tail brisket cow ribeye filet mignon. Tenderloin ribeye biltong,
    pig frankfurter swine pork chop brisket venison. Pig sirloin meatball turkey brisket cow landjaeger. Picanha pork loin ball tip, leberkas ham chuck kevin ground round turkey andouille corned beef drumstick. Pork belly jerky pork pastrami short loin
    kielbasa landjaeger ground round. Ball tip picanha shank beef ribs short ribs tri-tip, ham hock doner shoulder burgdoggen beef. Tenderloin pork chop prosciutto kielbasa drumstick corned beef landjaeger sausage burgdoggen. Venison jowl salami capicola
    ball tip beef biltong shankle turkey burgdoggen alcatra sausage. Pancetta tri-tip chuck tail drumstick salami turducken pork ball tip tongue tenderloin. Leberkas salami cow, strip steak cupim shoulder kevin beef pork belly swine prosciutto drumstick
    sausage bacon. Shank chicken meatball tongue ribeye leberkas boudin rump.</p>
</main>
```

Then add position: sticky and box-shadow

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

And witness header bar being moved to the right bottom. Remove the box-shadow and the content returns to its right position.

Is there any way to go around this issue without simply removing the position sticky if chrome 56 detected or placing an image with the shadow?

P.S. in my own project I am using angular and simply switching between position: relative to fixed doesn't work for certain reasons.

P.P.S. It seems that issue only affects HiDPI & Retina displays, I can reproduce it on my MBP & on my Ultra-Wide Full HD Monitor https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=698291&q=position%3A%20sticky&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/Nikki1993/1q0xy4n3/1/

Comment: Chrome : 56.0.2924.87 in W7 does not seems to show me the behavior you describe. (experimental CSS flagged on, no plugins beside adblock )

Comment: It seems that issue only affects HiDPI & Retina displays, I can reproduce it on my MBP & on my Ultra-Wide Full HD Monitor https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=698291&q=position%3A%20sticky&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified